python binance depth cache and websocket conflicts
i am using python binance and tring to work with ThreadedDepthCacheManager and ThreadedWebsocketManager at the same time.
each works seperatlly but together i am getting RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
thanks ahead
my code is
bookListener = ThreadedDepthCacheManager()
bookListener.start()
klineListener = ThreadedWebsocketManager()
klineListener.start()

bookListener.start_depth_cache(callback=self.handle_depth_message, symbol="BTCUSDT")
klineListener.start_kline_socket(callback=self.handle_kline_message, interval=enums.KLINE_INTERVAL_1SECOND ,symbol="BTCUSDT")

bookListener.join()
klineListener.join()

Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "D:\Dev\Binance\venv\lib\site-packages\binance\threaded_stream.py", line 61, in run
self._loop.run_until_complete(self.socket_listener())
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 563, in run_until_complete
self._check_runnung()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 523, in _check_runnung
raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
